# awk output to export variable

Tags: bash, awk, env

I have this command correctly build variable to export:

```
 dbus-daemon --session --fork --print-address | awk -F"dbus-" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F",guid=" '{print ("export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-" $1 ",guid=" $2)}'
```

The output is (correctly):

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-YaRPQ2SYD3,guid=fa6a614c14fa3a891db3ebca5467b08f
```

but i'm unable to export the result to env.

How can i do the trick ?
btw, i think there is a more efficient awk command to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(dbus-daemon --session --fork --print-address | awk -F"dbus-" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F",guid=" '{print ("unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-" $1 ",guid=" $2)}')
```

For future reference

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
var$(dbus-daemon --session --fork --print-address | awk -F"dbus-" '{ print $2 }' | awk -F",guid=" '{print ("export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-" $1 ",guid=" $2)}')
echo "$var"
```